# How to use ExSwift Array.toDictionary?

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

ExSwift has an Array extension:

```
    /**
    Converts the array to a dictionary with keys and values supplied via the transform function.

    :param: transform
    :returns: A dictionary
*/
func toDictionary <K, V> (transform: (Element) -> (key: K, value: V)?) -> [K: V] {
    var result: [K: V] = [:]
    for item in self {
        if let entry = transform(item) {
            result[entry.key] = entry.value
        }
    }

    return result
}
```

The ExSwift Wiki however only shows an example for the other toDictionary() method signature. I'm not yet very familiar with the way how these method signatures work. So I was wondering whether somebody can show me an example of how to use the above method call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a closure which takes as parameter element of the array and returns key - value pair.

Say you have an array of keys, and want to create a dictionary with default value for each key (let's say `0`):

```
let keys = ["a", "b", "c"]
let dictionary = keys.toDictionary { element in
    return (element, 0)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following the already mentioned sample from the wiki, we could guess the use of the second `toDictionary()` method:

```
class Person {
    let name: String, age: Int, id: String
    init(_ name: String, _ age: Int, _ id: String){
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.id = id
    }
}

let people = [
    Person("bob", 25, "P1"),
    Person("frank", 45, "P2"),
    Person("ian", 35, "P3")
]

let dictionary = people.toDictionary { $0.name, $0.age }
// → ["bob": 25, "frank": 45, "ian": 35]
```